# Join elements of a list into a path

Tags: filepath, python-2.6, os.path

I've got a list and I need to join th elements to form a path. os.join.path does not seem to work. The list is obtianed as:

```
    file_path.split("\\")[:-1]
```

this returns:

```
    ['L:', 'JM6', 'jm6', 'test', 'turb', 'results', 'v6.2', 'examples']
```

Using:

```
   print(os.path.join(file_path.split("\\")[:-1]))
```

returns exactly the same list without joining it into a path:

```
    ['L:', 'JM6', 'jm6', 'test', 'turb', 'results', 'v6.2', 'examples']
```

Using:

```
   print(os.path.join(os.path.sep, file_path.split("\\")[:-1]))
```

returns the error:

```
   print(os.path.join(os.path.sep, file_path.split("\\")[:-1]))
   File "C:\Python\lib\ntpath.py", line 73, in join
      elif isabs(b):
   File "C:\Python\lib\ntpath.py", line 58, in isabs
      return s != '' and s[:1] in '/\\'
 TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

os.path.join() doesn't take a list as argument, it takes several arguments.

using * (the 'splat' operator) should work:

```
list=['L:', 'JM6', 'jm6', 'test', 'turb', 'results', 'v6.2', 'examples']
os.path.join(*list)
```

Comment: It works but it misses the back slash after L: so its producing: L:JM62\..., rather than L:\JM62\...

Comment: inserted the \ as: `path = file_path.split("\\")[:-1]                                 
                                                                                                              path = os.path.join(*path)
                                                                                                              path = "\\J".join(path.split("J", 1))`

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, if you prefer pathlib, you can do

```
from pathlib import Path

mylist = ['L:', 'JM6', 'jm6', 'test', 'turb', 'results', 'v6.2', 'examples']
new_path = Path(*mylist)
```

for

PosixPath('L:/JM6/jm6/test/turb/results/v6.2/examples')

(or the windows path if you are on windows)

or

```
str(Path(*mylist))
```

for
'L:/JM6/jm6/test/turb/results/v6.2/examples'